# Why is fizzbuzz not working when the condition with two numbers comes after the conditions with one number?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to do the well known fizzbuzz problem in python, but do not understand, why Python is not checking the "combined" criteria.

Here is my code:

```
i = 0

while i + 1 < 100:
    i = i + 1
      
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print(str(i) + " fizz")
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print(str(i) + " buzz")
    elif (i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0):
        print(str(i) + " fizzbuzz")
    
    else:
        print(str(i))
```

I do not understand why it is not writing fizzbuzz in the cases where it can divide by 3 and 5.

I wanted to see either "fizz" or "buzz" or "fizzbuzz" but I only see "fizz" or "buzz". Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know why this works, but this works for me.

I just put the conditions checking both "things" on top.

Here:

```
i = 0

while i + 1 < 100:
    i = i + 1
    if (i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0):
        print(str(i) + " fizzbuzz")
    
    elif i % 3 == 0:
        print(str(i) + " fizz")
    elif i % 5 == 0:
        print(str(i) + " buzz")
    
    else:
        print(str(i))
```

I hope this works for you, sadly, I cannot explain why this is they way it is.

Comment: The explanation: Python checks the conditions in an `if ... elif ... else` from top to bottom, and the branch with the first true condition is chosen. In the case of fizzbuzz (e.g. 15, 30, 45, 60), all of `(i % 3 == 0 and i % 5 == 0)`, `i % 3 == 0`, `i % 5 == 0` are true, so you want to have the first (fizzbuzz one) first.

Comment: I do not understand I am sorry.

Comment: I am sorry...I feel this is not very nice. I try to be useful. I answered questions on Power Query or Power BI that were well received...yet I am not advanced in python or (coding as a whole for that matter)

Comment: Yes, I wasn't very nice. I apologize and deleted my comment. I was surprised and should have written that in another way ... or not at all.

Comment: No worries, sorry for my reaction as well. I know that I am not very bright, and this was a strong reminder, hence my reaction.

Comment: We have very specialized skills, that's all and it's got little to do with being bright. FWIW, I have only the faintest idea what Power Query or Power BI even are. I'd be lost! Thank you for posting an answer and being useful.